# Can't make if statement or ternary operator work inside .map() in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to bind the list `<li>` using `.map()` in React but it is not working out. To me it seems to be the issue of using either `(` or `{` properly. If I can get some guidelines here that would be so helpful.

While trying to bind the list, the code works as expected without any issue and without `if` statement.

As soon as I start writing `if` condition, it doesn't like it.

Here is my code that works without `if` statement. It is a simple list `<li>`.

```
let currentTopic = '';
return (
        <div>
            {
                <ul>
                    {   
                        topics.map((t) => (
                            <>
                              <span>{t.topicName}</span>
                              <li key={t.productId} value={t.subTopic}>
                                    {t.subTopic}
                              </li>
                            </>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    );
```

Below code I am trying to make it work with `if` statement. The `topicName` repeats depending on data in `topics` so by using `if` I am trying to put a check if it repeats than it should not print again. Something like below.

```
<ul>
   {   
      topics.map((topic) => (
             topic.topicName != currentTopic
                             ? (<><span>{topic.topicName}</span><li key={topic.productId} value={topic.subTopic}>
                                    {topic.subTopic}
                               </li></>) 
                             : null
                             ,currentTopic = topic.topicName
                        ))
  }
</ul>
```

I tried following below references from stackoverflow, but somehow I feel I am not able to set the syntax properly.

[if-condition-inside-of-map-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969877/if-condition-inside-of-map-react)

[if-condition-inside-map-react-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404514/if-condition-inside-map-react-js)

Comment: I didn't understand purpose of this line
`,currentTopic = topic.topicName`

Comment: when using ternary operator in react, make sure you wrap your conditions and returns in parentheses .e.g. `(condition) ? (if yes) : (if no)`. In your case, also wrap the entire return statement in the map function with parentheses, too. hopefully it works afterwards `(arg) => ((condition) ? (if yes) : (if no))`

Comment: @ShubhamNikam, that is one condition I try to check. if my `topic.topicName` has more than one occurrence than I omit them keep it unique. So I try to set a logic like storing `topic.topicName` in a variable and in next iteration I check whether it is same or not.

Answer (score 0):

Only using map without filter

```
<ul>
  {topics
    .map((topic) => (
       topic.topicName != currentTopic && 
      (<>
        <span>{topic.topicName}</span>
        <li key={topic.productId} value={topic.subTopic}>
          {topic.subTopic}
        </li>
      </>)
    ))}
</ul>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma operator (,)
The comma (,) operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand. This is commonly used to provide multiple updaters to a for loop's afterthought.

(topic.topicName != currentTopic ? () : null,currentTopic = topic.topicName)

It will return currentTopic = topic.topicName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) after the ternary condition in your `map` function.

```js
condition ? a : b, statement
```

This will be interpreted as

```js
((condition ? a : b), statement)
```

which will aways return `statement` after the comma operator, the return value of `currentTopic = topic.topicName`.

If you want to have some extra logic inside one of the ternary operation, consider changing the structure a little bit:

```js
condition ? a : (statement, b)
```

```
topics.map(topic =>
    topic.topicName != currentTopic ? (
        <>
            <span>{topic.topicName}</span>
            <li key={topic.productId} value={topic.subTopic}>
                {topic.subTopic}
            </li>
        </>
    ) : ((currentTopic = topic.topicName), null)
)
```

But as you can see, it's getting really messy here. My suggestion is to use a proper function body with if condition:

```js
topics.map(topic => {
    if (topic.topicName != currentTopic) {
        return (
            <>
                <span>{topic.topicName}</span>
                <li key={topic.productId} value={topic.subTopic}>
                    {topic.subTopic}
                </li>
            </>
        );
    } else {
        currentTopic = topic.topicName;
        return null;
    }
})
```